# Regular expression for positive decimal number with 0, 1 or 2 decimal places

Tags: regex

Please help me make regular expression for positive decimal number with 0, 1 or 2 decimal places. It must allow comma and dot.
For example it must allow:

```
0,01
0.01
0,1
1
1.1
1,11
```

but not allow:

```
-1
0.0
0,00
.01
0
1,111
1.111
```

I have this
`/(^\d*(?:\.|\,)?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*(?:\.|\,)\d*$)/`
but I can`t find how to disallow more than 2 decimal places.

**UPDATE**
I must reject 0.0, 0 and etc.

Comment: I will use it in jQuery custom validation method, so it for javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit 2: now disallows exactly 0,0.0, etc.**

This matches at least one digit before the decimal place, followed by an optional decimal place, followed by 0-2 digits.

**The negative lookahead looks for any flavor of absolute zero and prevents a match.**

```
^(?!0*[.,]0*$|[.,]0*$|0*$)\d+[,.]?\d{0,2}$
```

This is the raw regex, so you'll need to escape it appropriately for your language.  (For example, in some languages you need to double the `\` slashes as `\\`.

```
/^(?!0*[.,]0*$|[.,]0*$|0*$)\d+[,.]?\d{0,2}$/
```

Comment: Thank you! It's closer than other, but it still allows 0.  And can I make it to reject like this "00", "000" and etc?

Answer (score 3):

What you've got so far seems unnecessarily complicated to me. How about just

```
/^\d+([.,]\d{0,2})?$/
```

This is correct for every test case in the OP except for:

```
0.0
0,00
0
```

I don't see why you'd reject these.

Comment: Exactly and that is the problem here , it should not allow these `0` `0,0` etc

Answer (score 1):

you can use the bracket notion to limit the number of digits:

\d{0,2} would mean any run of digits from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 2

Comment: By itself, `\d{0,2}` erroneously matches `12` in the string `0.123456`. (It also matches the `34` and the `56`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\d+([.,]\d{1,2})?$/
```

this will properly disallow these "unformatted" numbers `.01`, `3.`, etc.

if we have zero decimal place digits we probably as well don't want the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

I've added whitespace and comments and parentheses to clarify it:

```
(                   #
  ( 0*[1-9]\d*   )  # a non-zero integer portion, followed by
  ( [\.,]\d{1,2} )? # an optional fraction of 1 or 2 decimal digits
)                   # 
|                   # OR
(                   #
  ( 0+ )            # a zero integer portion, followed by
  (                 # an mandatory non-zero 1-2 digit fraction, consisting of
    [\.,]           # a decimal point
    (               # followed by 
      ( 0[1-9]   )  # a 0 followed by a 1-9,
      |             # OR
      ( [1-9]\d? )  # a 1-9 followed by an optional decimal digit
  )
)
```

The regular expression is suboptimal it something like 0000000000.01 will backtrack when it doesn't find a non-zero digit following the zeros in the integer portion, but it should work.

Comment: I just realized my regex above will accept 0 w/o a fraction. Fixed!